# Value of Image data type in SQL Server display the image in angular 2.0, response in express

Tags: sql-server, node.js, angular, express

I am getting the response as below from express. I want to display this supertendentsSignature image in angular 2.

- Database: SQL Server
- Dataytpe : Image
- ORM: Sequelize
- Datatype of SuperintendentsSignature column is `Blob`
- Framework : Express
- Frontend : Angular 2.0

What can I do for this ? Can anybody help me?

```
{
    "status" : 'Active',
    "FName" : 'test',
    "SuperintendentsSignature": {
        "type": "Buffer",
        "data": [
            91,
            111,
            98,
            106,
            101,
            99,
            116,
            32,
            79,
            98,
            106,
            101,
            99,
            116,
            93
            ]
    }
}
```

Comment: `ntext`, `text`, and `image` data types will be removed in a future version of SQL Server. Avoid using these data types in new development work, and plan to modify applications that currently use them. Use `nvarchar(max)`, `varchar(max)`, and `varbinary(max)` instead. [See details here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms187993.aspx)

Comment: Yes, But, this system is being run. So, I cant change this. Any idea how to display the image ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Datauri npm is used to take the data uri from buffer object to display the image.

https://www.npmjs.com/package/datauri

```
const Datauri = require('datauri'),
const datauri = new Datauri();

//... 
const buffer = data.SuperintendentsSignature; // Buffer data 
//... 

datauri.format('.png', buffer);

console.log(datauri.content); //=> "data:image/png;base64,eGtjZA==" 
console.log(datauri.mimetype); //=> "image/png" 
console.log(datauri.base64); //=> "eGtjZA==" 
console.log(datauri.getCSS({
  class: "myClass",
  width: true,
  height: true
})); //=> adds image width and height and custom class name
```